# Changing background color by curselection() Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm facing an issue trying to change the background color by selecting it in the `OptionMenu`. The colors just don't change even if I add an `else` clause.

```
root=Tk()
root.geometry("200x200")
variative=IntVar()        
list=[1,2,3,4]
variative.set('Select')
listbox=OptionMenu(root,variative,list[0],list[1],list[2],list[3])
def Background(event):
    l=listbox.curselection()
    if l==1:
        root.config(bg='red')
    elif l==2:
        root.config(bg='yellow')
    elif l==3:
        root.config(bg='gray')
    elif l==4:
        root.config(bg='green')    
listbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>',Background)
listbox.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `OptionMenu` is not a `Listbox`, that's why the `<<ListboxSelect>>` event  never happens. However, you can pass a command option to the `OptionMenu` when you create it. This command will be called each time an option is selected in the menu and the selected option will be passed in argument.

Here is an example:

```
from tkinter import Tk, OptionMenu, IntVar
root = Tk()
variative = IntVar()        
option_list = [1,2,3,4]
variative.set('Select')

def background(sel):
    if sel == 1:
        root.config(bg='red')
    elif sel == 2:
        root.config(bg='yellow')
    elif sel == 3:
        root.config(bg='gray')
    elif sel == 4:
        root.config(bg='green')   

listbox = OptionMenu(root,variative, *option_list, command=background)
listbox.pack()
root.mainloop()
```